# Empty array in PHP version 5.5.12 in POST array

Tags: php, arrays

Could it be that there is a bug in PHP? When I want to read the global variable $_POST at start, it seems to contain a mysterious empty array.
`print_r($_POST);`
this returns array();

Thx a lot

Comment: Plz make it clear what is the problem.

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST)` yields ?

Comment: Post your code or snippet what you were facing

Answer (score -1):

Did you sended the form? If not, it's - of course - normal...
Be sure to have "post" in form tag type.
Or the request variable is an array.